# how can I loop over a collection in a sailsjs lifecycle method?

Tags: sails.js

I am new to sailsjs and so this is probably a simple thing but I can't seem to find what I want.  In my MyModel I want to loop over the things collection and get a list of the things.id fields (I am using mySQL) and stuff them into the values.schedule string and save that with the MyModel record. 
How can I do that in my afterUpdate or afterCreate method of MyModel? It needs to be done there because the things collection is populated when the MyModel is created.  Assume the MyThing model is very simple with just a name and its own id field and the MyModel.id field or reference.

```
 /**
 * MyModel.js
 */

module.exports = {

  schema: true,
  tableName: 'my_model',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,

  attributes: {

    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    things: {
      collection: "MyThing",
      via: 'MyModel'
    },

    schedule: {
      columnName: 'schedule',
      type: 'json',
      size: 512
    },
    ... other attributes ...

    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      return obj;
    }

  },

  .... other methods ...

  afterUpdate: function(values,  cb) {
    console.log('afterUpdate  : ', values);
    var things =  MyThing.find({
      where: {myModel: values.id},
      select: ['id']
    });
    console.log('MyModel afterUpdate  : ', things);
    cb();
  }
};
```

In the code above I would get the error:

```
ReferenceError: MyThing is not defined
```

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

This is the code that got me the things:

```
afterCreate: async function(values, next) {
...
  var things =  await MyThing.find({
      where:  {myModel: values.id},
      select: ['id']
    });
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`afterUpdate`takes as first argument `theUpdatedRecord`, so you can do something like this :

```
  afterUpdate: async function(updatedRecord,  cb) {
               console.log('afterUpdate  : ', updatedRecord);
               var things =  await MyModel.find({ id: 
               updatedRecord.id}).populate('things');
               var ids = things.map(thing => thing.id));
               console.log('MyModel afterUpdate  : ', ids); 
               cb();
              }
```

> `afterUpdate` will only be run on queries that have the `fetch` meta flag set to `true`.

Comment: In your code should that be MyModel.find or MyThing.find? It seems to be returning things with thing.id the same  as mymodel.id and of course only finding one.  The things have their own id and a field with the associated mymodel id -- mymodel_id.   I want to get the ids of all MyThings which have mything.mymodel_id same as updatedRecord.id.
Also I think I will need to use afterCreate instead as the new  MyThings will not be in the DB yet - the MyThing after* methods get called after the MyModel afterUpdate method gets called anyway.